# Concat String And JSON Payload Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I need concat string and json and pass into http post body but logic app always convert with back slash

INPUT
json = {"action":"UO","orderdetails":{"OrderID":"12345","PID":"PROD123"}}

OUTPUT REQUIRE
updateorder= {"action":"UO", "orderdetails" { "OrderID":"12345", "PID":"PROD123" } }

[image]

If I add updateorder=json below option logic app adding extra "\" in output so request is fail.

updateorder= {\"action\":\"UO\", \"orderdetails\" { \"OrderID\":\"12345\", \"PID":\"PROD123\" } }

[image]

Comment: Can you the preceding steps of your flow?  I tried to recreate and I don't have the issue.  i.e. what type of step is the `Body` coming from?  Is it `Parse JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a json function to turn it back into json

```
json(body('Name_of_action'))
```